# Declaring the change of address under two different statuses

Tags: usa, h1-visa, greencard, h4-visa

I entered the USA with a H1 visa, and my family entered the USA with H4 visas. This comes with various duties, including keeping my address up-to-date in the U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services (USCIS) records. We are also currently applying for a green-card, and already received our "combo cards". We moved recently (still inside the USA).

I went to the [USCIS page for the Change of Address](https://egov.uscis.gov/coa/addressChange.do) and declared our new address using our "[A-Numbers](https://www.uscis.gov/tools/glossary/number)". Those numbers were given *after* we entered the territory, with the green card application.

**Do I need to also declare our new address under our "visa" status?** I updated the records of my employers, but don't know if I should directly inform the USCIS of this change

Comment: By "combo cards," do you mean the card that serves both as advance parole and as employment authorization?  Also, the change of address form asks for your current status even if you enter an A number.  Didn't you state your current status when you submitted the form?

Comment: @phoog Yes, the combo card is the I-765 EAD/AP card. " the change of address form asks for your current status" : Yes, but I simply entered "Other -> H1 Visa", without providing more information.

Answer (score 2):

If you did the form online and have written confirmation/proof of having done it, I believe you're all set.

To explain how it relates to both your current and upcoming status, the [USCIS change of address information](https://www.uscis.gov/addresschange) page says that if you are changing address in the US and you have an application pending, then you must:

> Step 1: File Form AR-11 (online OR by mail);
>   AND
>   Step 2: Change your address on any pending or recently approved applications or petitions, online OR by phone at 1-800-375-5283. For TTY (deaf or hard of hearing) call: 1-800-767-1833.
>   Use our convenient Online Change of Address system to complete steps 1 and 2 at the same time. Once you complete Form AR-11 online - the system will also provide you the opportunity to change your address on any pending or recently approved applications. **If you use our Online Change of Address to complete Form AR-11, you do NOT need to file a paper Form AR-11.**

As I understand it, this means filling the online form is sufficient.

Lastly, if you have a lawyer working on your green card application, it's worth checking with them, as they will have recent experiences of the reliability or unreliability of changing one's address with USCIS.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to file a separate change of address "under your visa status."  You should have only one file at USCIS, which is identified by your A number.  There is in any event no other office that you could notify of your change of address.